# Using SQLite Manager to create indexes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite

I've created and index named "setIndex" for table "mySets" on column "setID" with the SQLite Manager (firefox). In order for the app to use them in a query, do I have to specify anything like the index name when searching my table?

SELECT * FROM mySets WHERE setID='setMatrix'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have anything more to do; you can't explicitly make SQLite use an index when running a query. The database engine (SQLite but that goes for all the others) will decide whether to use your index if it's there and if it considers it appropriate to do so.